# Keycloak default form

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, authorization, keycloak

I'm using keycloak, and I create  a new theme that inherits from the base parent and in the default register form I want to add a section for choosing a role, notice: the list of roles that I want it's based on my roles created in my realm is that possible?

I tried to modify the default registration form and adding a new section for choosing roles

Comment: I m working on keycloak version 12.0.4